# Proof-Verification :Evaluate $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{(n+1)(n+2)}.$

Tags: sequences-and-series

## Solution

\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{(n+1)(n+2)}&=\frac{1}{6}+\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{(n+1)(n+2)}\\
&=\frac{1}{6}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{H_n}{n+1}-\frac{H_n}{n+2}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{6}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{n+1}\left(H_{n-1}+\frac{1}{n}\right)-\frac{H_n}{n+2}\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{6}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{H_{n-1}}{n+1}-\frac{H_n}{n+2}\right)+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{6}+\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{H_n}{n+2}\right)+\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2}\\
&=1.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

It seems fine to me. You needn't separate out the $n=1$ term out from the start if you write $\frac{H_n}{n+1}-\frac{H_n}{n+2}$ as $\frac{H_n}{n+1}-\frac{H_{n+1}}{n+2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}$, reducing the final calculation to $\frac12+\frac12=1$. Either way, the telescoping with harmonic-over-linear terms requires the observation that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{H_n}{n}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

*Just added for your curiosity.*

You proof seems fine to me and, as J.G. answered, you could heve made it a bit simpler.

Whet is interesting is that, in the same spirit, you could have computed tha partial sums
$$S_p=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{p}\frac{H_n}{(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac{1+p}{2+p}-\frac{H_p}{2+p}$$ and useing asymptotics plus Taylor expansions
$$S_p=1-\frac{\log \left({p}\right)+\gamma +1}{p}+\frac{2 \log \left({p}\right)+2 \gamma +\frac{1}{2}}{p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approched. Moreover, it gives a quick way to approximate the result.

Foe example $S_{10}=\frac{221209}{332640}\approx 0.66501$ while the above expansion would give $\frac{10861-1008( \gamma + \log (10))}{12000}\approx 0.66318$.